# Uploading files using dojox.form.Uploader and FormData

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dojo

I am trying to upload files via XMLHttpRequest. I create a `input` with `type` set to `file` and get the file data using the below statement

```
var files = document.getElementById("fileInput").files;
var file = files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("fileInput", file);
.
.
.
xhr.send(formData);
```

This works! But when using the `dojox.form.Uploader` I wite something like this:

```
var files = dijit.byId("dojoFileInput").getFileList();
var file = files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("dojoFileInput", file);
.
.
.
xhr.send(formData);
```

This does **not** work! I cannot use the `upload` function of `dojox.form.Uploader` as I require some additional data to be sent in the `FormData` object. I am creating dojo file uploader using this statement

```
<div dojoType="dojox.form.Uploader" label="Select files..." id="dojoFileInput"></div>
```

I tried to print the file data in console using these statements:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("fileInput").files[0]); // Normal file input
var files = dijit.byId("dojoFileInput").getFileList(); // Dojo file input
console.log(files[0]);
```

The normal file input gives the following output (actually there is a lot more info. than this under each section but this is condensed):

```
File {webkitRelativePath: "", lastModifiedDate: Sat Nov 10 2012 19:42:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), name: "<FILE NAME>", type: "image/png", size: 115661}
    lastModifiedDate: Sat Nov 10 2012 19:42:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
        __proto__: Invalid Date
        name: "<FILE NAME>"
        size: 115661
        type: "image/png"
        webkitRelativePath: ""
    __proto__: File
        constructor: function File() { [native code] }
        arguments: null
        caller: null
        length: 0
        name: "File"
        prototype: File
        toString: function toString() { [native code] }
        __proto__: Object
        <function scope>
    __proto__: Blob
        constructor: function Blob() { [native code] }
        slice: function slice() { [native code] }
        webkitSlice: function webkitSlice() { [native code] }
        __proto__: Object
```

But the Dojo file uploader only gives a single line output:

```
Object {index: 0, name: "<FILE NAME>", size: 115661, type: "image/png"}
```

Does Dojo not give the entire file details that can be sent to server? Is this the right way to send files to server using dojo file uploader? Any ideas how his can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Uploader has a *submit* method that allows you to add post data.

Comment: Hi @mwilcox is there something in between the submit that I can use to make sure if the file will pass certain conditions before upload? I get "failed:connection reset" in google chrome (which is due to directory permissions). I do get exceptions returned by _HTML5.js and ProgressEvent but nothing helpful.